# PHP, PDO, SLIM framework, JSON encoding UTF8

Tags: php, json, utf-8, slim, urlencode

Have some trouble with PDO and Slim framework. Point is I don't know how I can change to utf8 char. I was reading the whole internet but nothing work for me. My JSON respone should looks like "ćśąęł" but is "\u0107\u015b\u0105\u0119\u0142" and in my android app is "?????" I checked encoding in all files and programs I'm using and it is set to utf8.

my PDO

```
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $pdo -> query('SELECT id, title, opinion, upload_image FROM upload_post LIMIT '.$offset.',8');
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pdo = null;
        echo json_encode("ćśąęł");
    }catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo 'Połączenie nie mogło zostać utworzone: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
    }
```

what I tried

```
$pdo->exec("set names utf8");
array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'')
charset=utf8 in connection string 
$app = new \Slim\Slim();$app->contentType('text/html; charset=utf-8'); in Slim framework, but still nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, so this is working for me 
in connection String add charset=utf8 like

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
```

and in Json encode add "JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE" <- this method work in php above 5.3 example here

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

and all my pdo

```
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $pdo -> query('SELECT id, title, opinion, upload_image FROM upload_post LIMIT '.$offset.',8');
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pdo = null;
        echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo 'Połączenie nie mogło zostać utworzone: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }
```

Good Luck ;)